# How to save background as UIimage from uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: xcode, uiimage, xcode4.2, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a View to get and set image from photo gallery.

I want to call the image from another view and set the uiimage as background.

What is the best method to make the image stay as a background like iPhone default background feature?

My codes are modified version from here: http://blog.hanpo.tw/2012/01/uiimagepickercontroller-and-simple.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use a UIImageView :

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentOfFile:@"path/of/myImage.png"]]
```

You can pass the path to your image as an argument and store it or copy the file under the name "background.png" for example, and each time you change it you delete the file and create the new "background.png".